# Inserting and Deleting data in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark Dataframe **input_dataframe** as shown below:

```
**cust_id**   **source_id**     **value**
   10              11          test_value
   10              12          test_value2
```

i have another dataframe **delta_dataframe** which have updated records from input_dataframe and some new records as shown below:

```
**cust_id**   **source_id**     **value**
   10              11          update_value
   10              15          new_value2
```

In Both dataframe, primary key is combination of **cust_id** and **source_id**.

I have to generate a new dataframe **output_dataframe**, which will have records from **input_dataframe** with updated records from **delta_dataframe**, so my final dataframe is as below:

```
**cust_id**   **source_id**     **value**
   10              11          update_value
   10              12          test_value2
   10              15          new_value2
```

Can someone please suggest me, how can i achieve it in PySpark. Any help will be appreciated on this.

Comment: `oldDF.join(newDF,Seq("cust_id","source_id"),"LEFT").select(newDF.columns:_*)`... this is how it can be done in spark using scala.... python will have similar method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract the two dataframes based on primary key. Make inner join of output with input_dataframe. Then take Uion of it with Delta_dataframe. You will get proper output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join `input_dataframe` and `delta_dataframe` using join on two columns

```
output_df = input_df.join(delta_df, input_df['cust_id'] = delta_df['cust_id'] & input_df['source_id'] = delta_df['source_id'], 'left_outer')
```

And then select only the required fields from `output_df`

Comment: It did not create required output_dataframe for me.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Outer join and select the required dataframe value,

```
>>> input_dataframe.join(delta_dataframe,['custid','sourceid'],'outer').select('custid','sourceid',F.coalesce(delta_dataframe['value'],input_dataframe['value']).alias('value')).show()
+------+--------+-------------+
|custid|sourceid|        value|
+------+--------+-------------+
|    10|      15|   new_value2|
|    10|      11|updated_value|
|    10|      12|  test_value2|
+------+--------+-------------+
```